# Zend Studio/Eclipse shows expanded folder names

Tags: php, eclipse, zend-studio

I created a project from and existing code base but now in the PHP explorer i see folders will the full path in them.

for example:

1st folder core

2nd subfolder core/config

i want it to read as follows:

1st folder core

2nd subfolder config

Take note it's an SVN project.

Comment: @AR ZendStudio 8.0.0? It seems they made a quick conversion from the Java based system, while they have to refine the tool for php... Anyway, try to look at the Include Path (at the bottom of the project in Explorer)...

Comment: The question is vague. Please clarify the problem. Maybe add a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in the upper right corner of your explorer view. You should see a downward facing triangle. Click it to activate view settings menu. Go to Package Presentation -> Hierarchical.

Comment: "Package Presentation" does not exist in my PHP Explorer in ZS 8.0.

Comment: I'd poke around for a similar setting. If you don't find it, then file a bug on Zend. In the meantime, you can open another navigational view, such as the generic Project Explorer. It may not have all the PHP features, but it will allow for folder presentation that you want.

Comment: I cannot reproduce any of this in my Zend Studio. If you are sure this works in Zend Studio, provide a screenshot please. Otherwise I'd say the answer is wrong (though it's hard to tell given that the initial question is already hard to comprehend)

Comment: I don't use ZS, but Eclipse plugins (ZS included) borrow extensively from each other. I have pointed out where to look for this setting if it exists and where to complain if it doesn't. You can also mix and match views from different plugins, such as using Project Explorer for PHP development if it has the features you want, even if Zend doesn't directly intend it to be used.